# iOS: How can I add border images for a button in my nav bar?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'd like to add a bar button item to my navigation bar and give it some border images that look like vertical lines (circled in red in the image below)...

[image]

The background of the barbutton item is going to clear, as I'm setting the background image of the entire navigation bar separately.  The text is going to be dynamic, so I can't bake either the text or the lines into a background image and then set that background image for the bar button item.  I just need to add these vertical line images on either side of the bar button item.

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: any padding attribute you can edit?

Comment: hey @owengerig, i'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a stretchable UIImage as a background for an UIButton and then init the bar button item with the UIButton as a custom view:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *bgImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonBorder.png"]
    resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10)]; // or whatever size suits your needs
[btn setBackgroundImage:bgImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
```

etc.